# Bootstrap Affix - any tutorial about data-offset-bottom?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have tried look for so many affix tutorial out there, but all of them talk about data-offset-top. Anybody here know about tutorial of data-offset-bottom?? 
i have tried writing some code here 
https://jsfiddle.net/okiewardoyo/3m8oeLp5/

Form above jsfiddle, i try using data-offset-top,

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
```

What i want is, when user scroll until footer apear, the yellow side bar become not fix and follow the footer. 
I think, we can use data-offset-bottom here. But how to do that?? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [tutorial from W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp) I think is clear enough for your problem also there is some easy tutorial [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstraps-affix-scrollspy-plugins/)

The offset top or bottom only indicate in which part is going to be "fixed" (This is optional information). Since you want it to stop the position when the affix is in the bottom (class changed to affix-bottom) 
This position should be absolute so the element don't continue applying affix (Usually the problem is that the class affix-bottom is not being applied).

To do this dinamically you can use jQuery and the affix function as It's said in both links any other way you have to hard-assign this value (the height of the footer).
Position assigned

`#nav1.affix-bottom {
      position: absolute;
    }`

How the nav looks:

```
`<ul id="nav1" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" data-offset-bottom="600">`
```

[Your example working](https://jsfiddle.net/twkthn44/1/) (actually i also move the nav from its container, but works in any way)

Comment: Thanks so much, your example is what i want. I have re-fiddle your code here https://jsfiddle.net/okiewardoyo/twkthn44/2/ , that is what i want. When i scroll, the section become fix, and after reach footer, the section become not fix and follow the footer.

Comment: But i'm curious, if i used jquery to calculate footer height, how to do that?? i have found another sample using this data-offset-bottom http://jsfiddle.net/uvnGP/131/ , but sometimes when i scroll down, the customer info doesn't fix properly

Comment: There is a method [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) easy to use. It's all about to give the appropiate information to the class (for example the correct bottom offset). If you are satisfied with the question mark it so this question can be useful for other persons. The second example that you write down in the comment is not stoping at the footer boundarie because they use var footerHeight = $('footer').innerHeight(); instead of height, what gives the height of the inner part of the rectangle.

Comment: I change var footerHeight = $('footer').innerHeight(); to var footerHeight = $('footer').height(); but not solve the problem, Try it http://jsfiddle.net/uvnGP/131/

Comment: On a somewhat related note with my screen res set `1280x1024` in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/petersmm/9yt1w3dj/2/. Why does it jitter when scrolling? It has a seizure, flat-out.